# Testing VECM coefficients

Tags: r, time-series, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model

I read questions about vector error correction models (VECM) and cointegration, and then realized that most concern the error correction term instead of the other coefficients in the model.

My (short) question: In `R`, how can one test the joint significance of the coefficients on the differenced variables of the VECM? (The usual Wald test does not work in the same way as it does for VAR models)

Comment: If you already know the Wald test does not work, then the same source perhaps have some suggestions for a valid alternative? Have you tried Lutkepohl's textbook on mutivariate time series?

Comment: Yes, Lütkepohl's and Hamilton's book ("Time Series Analysis") are my main sources. Unfortunately, I sometimes have a hard time in understanding their content, I apologize if I misunderstood anything. At the same time, I try to learn how to conduct the tasks in `R`. The problem is that I assume the usual `wald.test` command is not the right way to go to conduct hypothesis tests in a VECM because I have never seen it suggested and I do not yet get how other tests work that are advocated. I wondered if there is a simple explanation of how to conduct tests on the coefs of a VECM.

Comment: Have you checked the manual and the vignette of the "vars" package? I remember there being functions to test hypotheses, but probably they all focused on the error correction part...

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not find any function which enables one to test hypothesis on VECM coefficients. What I _did_ discover is that it is possible to transform the VECM into a VAR model which makes hypothesis testing (on the VAR coefficients then) pretty straightforward. However, I do not know whether I am allowed to do this. Do you happen to know whether this approach is valid? (Or is this a subject for a new question?)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if this is valid. I suspect it should not be so simple... +1 for the question.